# Python Pyinstaller Exe Throws FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: json, python-3.x, initialization, executable, pyinstaller

Before writing this here i have read many ariticles and this forum post as well none solved my problem and this stops me progressing further.

any cleaner solution would be appreciated.

Converted python scripts(3.6) to single file .exe in pyinstaller.

exe creation is successful,when i run the exe in command window (using windows 7)
it throws error as below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "strategy.py", line 62, in <module>
    s = Session(api_key)
  File "site-packages\upstox_api\api.py", line 48, in __init__
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\MBALAS~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI84682\\upstox_api\\service_config.json'
[10096] Failed to execute script strategy
```

the strange part is  "upstox_api" is present in C:python\script folder but it is looking in Temp folder quiet confused.

Any help to resolve this and to create a clean exe is really need of the hour and i appreciate your effort and support in advance.

Note :[Link](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/How-to-Report-Bugs#Make%20sure%20everything%20is%20packaged%20correctly) referred this post as well and tried the details given still could not resolve this.

Tried py2exe an CX_Freeze as well none works.

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve this. im having similar challenges

Comment: I solved it and posted the solution ,Moderator removed it .Let me know if i can share the result in any other way. 5 votes remaining to share the result. Make the vote

Comment: where do i make the vote? that said, could you use pastebin :)

Comment: Please refer to this https://gist.github.com/GaryLee/d191f239acf2f47bec93

Comment: turns out what caused the error was different, fixed it though. Thanks for the quick response.